# Tracking source code information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a web application that I have created using ruby on rails, is there a way that I can track which users of my web application have viewed the source code of a specific page?

Comment: "View Source" is client functionality; I don't see how. You might be able to do something with included pages and the refer link, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The application just sends the source to a browser, has no way of knowing whether or not the user of that browser decided to look at the source code for the page, or just view the rendered page as normal.

This isn't specific to Rails - it's just a fact about how webpages work.

JavaScript-based tracking code (Google Analytics et al.) can tell you about users whose browsers render the page (assuming they don't block it in one of various ways), but still won't be able to tell if the user viewed the source.